# How I can join two FQL queries into one query.?

Tags: c#, wpf, fql.multiquery

Hi I have Two Different Queries one is for `username` and second is for retrieving `Messages` and `actor_id`

so how I can combine both query and getting my correct result.
my queries like.

```
var Query1 = fbApp.Query("SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

var newsFeed = fbApp.Query("SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0");
```

thank you..!!

Answer (score -2):

The [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) method allows you to combine both results (provided both return an enumeration of the same type). [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) can help you find only users that exist in both lists.

From MSDN:

```
int[] ints1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
int[] ints2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };

IEnumerable<int> union = ints1.Union(ints2);

foreach (int num in union)
{
     Console.Write("{0} ", num);
}
/*
This code produces the following output:

5 3 9 7 8 6 4 1 0
*/
```

So for you something like this:

```
var combinedList = Query1.Union(newsFeed);
```

Comment: this will give me erro this is not my result.

Comment: Can you provide more information as to the type of error you're getting doing this? What are the types of "Query1" and "newsFeed"

Comment: Both are JsonArray type it simple says can't  convert from object to JsonArray.